# Middleware for ERPs like SAP, Netsuite, Microsoft Dynamics

Tags: netsuite, middleware, microsoft-dynamics, erp, sap-erp

I am looking for connectors/Middlewares that can be used to integrate any third party application with the widely used ERPs for eg: a. Oracle EBS b. Netsuite c. Sage ERP d. SAP ERP e. Microsoft Dynamics

Are there any connectors/Middlewares available that are recommended to use for this.

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: Havn't you already asked this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844009/integration-of-third-party-erps-with-common-erps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integration of Third Party ERPs with common ERPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844009/integration-of-third-party-erps-with-common-erps)

Answer (score 0):

Mulesoft ESB has pre-built connectors for [most of those](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/#!/netsuite-integration-connector).

I have a large customer who has used it at the core of their Netsuite integration strategy for a number of years.